# Weighted clustering in sklearn

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, dbscan

Assuming I have a set of points (x,y and size). I want to find clusters in my data using `sklearn.cluster.DBSCAN` and their centers. That is no problem if I treat every point the same. But actually I want the weighted centers instead of the geometrical centers (meaning a bigger sized point should be counted more than a smaller) .

I came across with `sample_weight`, but I don't quite get if that is what I need. When I use `sample_weight` (right side) I get completely different clusters to the case when I don`t use it (left side):

[image]

Second I thought about using `np.repeat(x,w)` where x is my data and w is the size of each point so I get multiple copies of the points proportional to their weights. But this is probably not a smart solution as I get a lot of data, right?

Is `sample_weight` useful in my case or are there suggestions for better solutions than using `np.repeat`? I know that there are some questions about `sample_weight` already, but I could not read out how to use it exactly.

Thanks!

Comment: it is a method of `sklearn.cluster.DBSCAN`. I use it by: `fit_predict(self, X[, y, sample_weight])`

Answer (score 1):

The most important thing for DBSCAN is the parameter setting. There are 2 parameters, `epsilon` and `minPts` (=`min_samples`). The epsilon parameter is the radius around your points and `minPts` considers your points as a part of a cluster if `minPts` is fulfilled. So instead of using `np.repeat` I would suggest adjusting the parameters for this dataset.

According to the documentation of [DBSCAN](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.DBSCAN.html), `sample_weight` is a tuning parameter for your runtime:

> Another way to reduce memory and computation time is to remove
>   (near-)duplicate points and use sample_weight instead.

I think you want to address the quality of your result first before you tune your runtime.

I am not sure what you mean with weighted centers, probably you are refering to a differt clustering algorithm such as [Gaussian mixture model](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/mixture.html).

Comment: Well, they are already weighted, right. Isn't that what density-based means? It would be much more helpful if you shared your actual data and your actual code, unless it's proprietary. I would say the algo is doing exactly what it is supposed to do.